# Multiple Buttons Link under the same column in wicket

Tags: wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.5

Is it possible to provide two button under the same column of a Listview in Wicket
I am able to do the same for two hyperlink but somehow i am facing difficulties in creating two buttons.

[image: something like this mentioned in Action column]

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Sure, it is possible! Show us your code and we will tell you what is not correct.

Comment: If you know how to do it with hyperlinks you can also just use CSS styles to make the Link look like a button (example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#button-tags)

Comment: thank you for your comment.The above url helped a lot.